# Envelope distribution for rejection sampling from $(Beta/Beta)*Normal$

Tags: distributions, bayesian, normal-distribution, beta-distribution, rejection-sampling

I want to obtain random variates from a random variable whose probability density function is $$q(log(\sigma_t)|a_1, b_1, a_2, b_2, \sigma_{t-1},\lambda) = \frac{1}{C}\frac{\mathcal{B}(a_1; \sigma_ta_1, \sigma_tb_1)}{\mathcal{B}(a_1; \sigma_{t-1}a_2, \sigma_{t-1}b_2))}\mathcal{N}(log(\sigma_t); log(\sigma_{t-1}),\lambda)$$
for $\sigma, \sigma_{t-1}\in(0,+\infty)$, $a_1, b_1, a_2, b_2 \in (0,1)$, and $\lambda\gt 0$.  $\mathcal{B}$ is the Beta distribution pdf, $\mathcal{N}$ is the Normal distribution pdf, and $C$ is the normalizing constant (for further details see equation 28 in this [article](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/4203044/)). I can use adaptive rejection sampling as the distribution is log-concave. However, I wonder if I can find an envelope distribution in closed form that I can use in rejection sampling.

My idea was the following: both $\mathcal{B}$ and $\mathcal{N}$ are from exponential families and so perhaps I can find another distribution from an exponential family that is easy to sample from at the same time. However, I couldn't find such a distribution.

Any suggestions on how to obtain the random variates?

Comment: What do you mean by "uniform"? Presumably not uniform as in U(0,1). And what is the meaning of this product of three distributions?

Comment: Why not just generate three random variables from the three distributions involved and perform the requisite operations to get $q$?  This will save you a huge amount of time, probably far more than developing a custom RNG will ever gain you in runtime.

Comment: I have edited the question to clrafiy. @Xi'an I want to obtain random variates from a distribution whose probability density function (pdf) is product and division of other pdfs. For example, $q(3) = (\mathcal{B}(3; a_1, b_1)/\mathcal{B}(3; a_2, b_2))*\mathcal{N}(3; \mu, \sigma^2)$.

Comment: @jbowman I don't want to calculate the pdf at a given point. If I want to calculate $q(3)$, for instance, I could do that as you said. However, I want to generate random variates from the distribution.

Comment: $q$ doesn't integrate to 1, it's not a density as your question claims. Do you mean $q$ is proportional to a density? If so, how confident are you that this will be the case with all combinations of parameter values?

Comment: @Glen_b You are right, I editted the question. It is proportional to that density. The parameters in the density are fixed. So, it is guarenteed it sums up to 1 for some fixed parameters.

Comment: @Xi'an I have made another edit. The parameters are fixed.

Comment: @yasin You also seem to miss the point I was getting at I think; how do you know it has a finite integral at *whatever fixed set of parameters you're dealing with*? I can  identify combinations of parameter values on the unit interval for which the integral doesn't seem to converge. How do you know you're not in that situation?

Comment: @Xi'an Yeah, i missed that part when i tried to simplify the problem. Now thay all have the same support as well.

Comment: You can simplify the presentation by absorbing the denominator into $C$, yielding something like $$q(x;a,b,\mu,\sigma)=\frac{1}{C}\mathcal{B}(a;e^xa,e^xb)\mathcal{N}(x;\mu,\sigma).$$  (I suspect there are still problems with how you have expressed the denominator--it makes no sense when $\sigma_{t-1}\le 0$--but this simplification avoids that issue.) Because the left hand side is *not* a Beta distribution for $x$ or $e^x$, it may be misleading to characterize this as a "Beta/Beta * Normal" in the title. It's part of the joint distribution for a Beta with a (bivariate) lognormal prior.

Comment: @whuber when i tried simplifying the problem, i missed several parts. it is better this way i think. in your try, for example, your notation misses that the domain of log function is positive, so is $sigma_{t-1}.$

Comment: Yes, making a mistake in the simplification is a risk.  That's why I offered my comment about it. I do not, however, understand the rest of your criticism.  First, my formulation does not use the logarithm at all.  Second, the restriction on the domain of $\sigma_{t-1}$ is obvious, you have already clearly stated it, and (for this question) it is irrelevant.